# Will android services stop when I receive a phone call?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a doubt in Android services. I wrote a simple application with a service that runs continuously and upload data to server. My doubt is that will the service stop when I receive a phone call? Will it run in background when I make phone call or will it stop. Please give me an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: From docs The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus.

Answer (score 1):

Activities stop, however services do not. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

Services run on the background no matter what happen on the screen. It only stops if you stop it using stop or exit function of its main application or you stop the services in Settings. 
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Unless the available phone memory was already low to begin with because you have a lot of apps running in the background, only then *might* Android forcibly close the service to accommodate the phone call.

Comment: In such case if memory becomes less while running the service for a long time, and the service stops, Is there any method to get rid of this situation? I need my service to run through out until I stop the service and my phone is on. Can you please tell me a method to do this?